# pass <tr> id value javascript function

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to pass `<tr>` **id value** instead for `this.id` , How to get tr id value. please help me thanks

```
<tr id="1">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this.id)" value="private" name="private" id="private_1">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this.id)" checked="" value="public" name="public" id="public_1">
    </td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr id="2">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this.id)" checked=""  value="private" name="private" id="private_2">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this.id)" value="public" name="public" id="public_2">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sasindu555/B26f3/)**

Comment: Your "demo" is not doing anything. You could at least have implemented some dummy `toggle` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the structure is exactly like this, you can use

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.id
```

Of course this will brake as soon as the structure changes.

Instead of binding to the `click` event, you should bind to the `change` event. Then you also cover changes made by the keyboard.

---

As every handler is doing the same, you should consider to leverage [*event bubbling*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). Instead of attaching the event handler to every `input` element in your HTML, attach only *one* event handler to the table:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableId');

table.onchange = function(event) {
   event = event || window.srcElement;  // IE specials
   var target = event.target || event.srcElement;  // IE specials

   // was the element a checkbox?
   if(target.nodeName === "INPUT" && target.type === "checkbox") {
       // find parent row
       var parent = target.parentNode;
       while(parent.nodeName !== "TR" && parent !== null) {
           parent = parent.parentNode;
       }

       if(parent) { // we found the row
           toggle(parent.id);
       }
   }
};
```

This looks more complicated but has the advantage that you don't have to write `onclick="toggle(this.id)"` on every `input` element.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/9JsFm/)